# How to remove tabbed pan view from World wind measure tool

Tags: java, swing, worldwind

I am working on the Nasa World wind measure tool. I want to know how can I remove the tabbed pan from it .

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the World Wind Measure Tool sample application then you need to remove the following lines of code from MeasureToolUsage.java (roughly at line 82)

```
this.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
```